# Lock out a key in Memcache

Tags: synchronization, locking, memcached

I'm trying to find a way to prevent a particular key in memcache from being
written for a specified period of time,  e.g. 5 minutes.

I can imagine doing something like below,  but it would require an extra
"get" for every "set"

```
function lock($key,$expiration) {
  memcache::set($key,'DONTUSEME', $expiration);
}


function set_key($key,$val) {
  if(memcache::get($key) == 'DONETUSEME') {
     # no-op
  } else {
     memcache::set($key,$val);
  }
}

function get_key($key) {
   $val = memcache::get($key);
   if($val == 'DONTUSEME') {
      return '';
   } else {  
      return $val;
   }
}
```

Comment: Turns out there used to be a feature called "lingering delete" which was close to this functionality.   Removed from memcache,  I can't tell why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memcached does not allow you to lock keys. You could potentially look into Couchbase though since it does have a "get and lock" command and uses the same protocol as memcached. Couchbase is a database, but it contains a memcached caching layer on top. I can provide more details if you want to try this solution. There may also be other caching solutions that do implement a lock command, but I can not think of any off the top of my head.

Comment: Note that I've heard that riak and redis might also provide some sort of lock functionality. The implementation details might be different between products though.

Answer (score 0):

A year later - memcache doesn't seem able to do this.

Redis definitely has locking functinoality, via SETNX.   Redis is competitive with Memcache, performance-wise.

http://redis.io/commands/setnx

**SETNX key value**

**Set key to hold string value if key does not exist. In that case, it is equal to SET. When key already holds a value, no operation is performed. SETNX is short for "SET if N ot e X ists.**